# Successive overrelaxation method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Given the following set of linear equations
\begin{align} \begin{bmatrix}4&2&0&0\\1&4&1&0\\0&1&4&2\\0&0&2&4\end{bmatrix} x = 
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\end{align}
I need to execute first step of the successive overrelaxation method from the starting point \begin{align} x^0 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\ 0\end{bmatrix} \end{align}

I based on information from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_over-relaxation) and my question is how to find omega (ω) for this formula?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/loci/joma/iterative-methods-for-solving-iaxi-ibi-the-sor-method) help? Find the sentence "optimal convergence is achieved by choosing a value".

Answer (score 0):

Let $Ax=b$ be the equation system.
Are you sure, that the entry $a_{2,1}$ equals 1 and not 2?

Because this looks like a homework question, and SOR without a symmetric positive definite matrix is meh.

---

For example SOR will converge for any $ω∈(0,2)$ if $A$ is symmetric, positive definite.

Additionally if $A$ is s.p.d.  then there is a connection of the spectral radius (largest eigenvalue) of the SOR matrix $$H_ω=[D+ωL]^{-1}[(1-ω)D-ωR]$$
and the Jacobi-Matrix
$$J=-D^{-1}(L+R).$$
Here I used the notation $A=L+D+R$, splitting matrix $A$ into a lower-triangular matrix $L$, the diagonal $D$ and the upper-triangular matrix $R$.

Assuming $ρ_J:=\operatorname{spr}(J)<1$, it holds:
$$\operatorname{spr}(H_ω)=\begin{cases}ω-1 & ω\geqslant ω_{opt} \\ \frac{1}{4}\left[ρ_Jω+\sqrt{ρ_J^2ω^2 - 4(ω-1)}\,\right]^2 &ω\leqslantω_{opt}\end{cases}$$

Now the SOR method converges fastest, if $\operatorname{spr}(H_ω)$ is minimal. This gives us the formula: 
$$ω_{opt} = \frac{2(1-\sqrt{1-ρ_J^2})}{ρ_J^2}.$$

---

Still assuming that $a_{2,1}=2$
The eigenvalues of $J$ are: 
`[-0.6403882 -0.3903882  0.6403882  0.3903882]`, so $\operatorname{spr}{J}\approx0.64$.
And therefore $ω_{opt}\approx 1.130$.

---

Edit: Since you have asked several question, but never marked an answer as correct, allow me this remark. It would be nice, if you would show appreciation to everyone who helped you with your past questions by upvoting good answers, and marking them as solution, if they solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am sure that $a_2,_1 = 1$. Moreover, it is not my homework, but it was a task on my exam. I still don't know how to solve this in case of  $a_2,_1 = 1$. Anyway, thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: In that case, I don't know any nice formula. And the only way I can think of, is to calculate eigenvalues of $H_ω$ and minimizing their upper bound.  That is, because the spectral radius determines the speed of convergence.